# Count total balls from cricket overs and sum overs (mssql)

Tags: sql-server

I'm creating a stored procedure in SQL Server for a cricket application. How can I find the total number of balls, given there are 6 balls in an over.

Suppose there are 4 overs. We can easily calculate 4 * 6. But what if there were 4.5 overs? I also want to sum the two different cricket matches over of a particular bowler over.

For example:

match1 overs 4.5 
match2 overs 6.3 
addition should be  11.2

With a calculator we get 10.8

Here is what I tried

```
COALESCE(Sum(Overs),0) * 6  + (COALESCE(Sum(Overs),0) - COALESCE(Sum(Overs),0))* 10 as Totalballs,
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Provide sample data for your question. Help people to help you

Comment: @Ingaz no1: i just want to know the formula , u may suppose if a bowler bowls 3.5 overs it means he delivered 23 balls, how can i calculate this ,

Comment: no2: a bowler delivered 4.5 over in first match and 5.2 over in 2nd match , it means total overs he delivered 10.1 , what calculator gives us output is 9.7 ,

Comment: 4.5 * 6 wouldn't work? Your table and expected data would help

Comment: I don't think `(COALESCE(Sum(Overs),0) - COALESCE(Sum(Overs),0))` will ever not equal 0

Comment: @scsimon 4.5 * 6 will give 27 , but as we know there are 6 balls in one cricket over so 4.5 means 4 overs and 5 balls, so it means, 4*6 = 24 + 5 = 29 , this is desired result,

Comment: @Andy my point is not here about (COALESCE(Sum(Overs),0) - COALESCE(Sum(Overs),0)) will ever gives equals 0 or not, but its gives equal to 0 for further calculation when i will go to find economy rate of a bowler,

Answer (score 4):

Based on your last comment, we can first `FLOOR` the over to find what the first multiple will be.

Then we subtract the over from that, convert to INT, and add.

```
declare @over decimal(4,1) = 4.5
select
    SixeTimesThis = floor(@over) 
    ,Remainder = (@over - floor(@over))
    ,RemainderAsInt = cast(replace((@over - floor(@over)),'.','') as int)
    ,FinalResult = floor(@over) * 6 +cast(replace((@over - floor(@over)),'.','') as int)
```

Comment: You bet @FarazShaikh I don't know anything about Cricket as you can probably tell by my questions :)

Comment: ya i got an idea, after all this u made my day i had to solve so many queries and it was just a pre-breaker

Answer (score 4):

You can use modulus `%` to get the extra balls.

**Example snippet:**

```
select *, coalesce(floor(Overs)*6 + floor((Overs%1)*10), 0) as Balls
from (values 
 (1.0),
 (4.0), 
 (4.5),
 (null)
) as v(Overs);
```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=f1a733274d252edcac15175a94e01be3)*

**Result:**

```
Overs Balls
----- -----
1.0   6
4.0   24
4.5   29
NULL  0
```

Comment: Coffee has t kicked in. +1 for MOD. Much cleaner